# How do I solve this equation analytically?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have attempted to solve the equation many times analytically but unfortunately I got to a point where I cannot further proceed. The equation:

$$T(t)e^{0.269} =\int6.187e^{0.269}dt + \int-0.807 \sin\left(\frac \pi{12}t\right)e^{0.269}dt$$

The point I got to:
$$(0.296)T(t) =(23)(0.296t) + \ln\left(0.807e^{0.296}+\cos\left(\frac \pi{12}t\right)-\frac \pi{12}\right)+ \ln\left(C-\frac \pi{12}\right)$$

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: $e^{0.269}$ can be simplified. Are you sure ?

Comment: And how do you get this logarithm ???

Comment: Hopefully I did not misinterpret your images, since it seems that the constant $e^{0.269}$ can be factored out at the start, and in your work, the factor $0.296$ and the $\ln$ term came out of nowhere.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to solve in terms of what.

Comment: I want to solve for T(t)

Comment: Do you mind doing the equation in term of T(t) from the beginning maybe I did a mistake.

Comment: Just divide the original equation by $e^{0.269}$ and you have an expression for $T(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

We can divide by $e^{0.269}$, and we'd get

$$ T(t) = \int 6.187 \mathrm{d}t + \int -0.807 \sin \Biggl ( \dfrac{\pi}{12} t \Biggr ) \mathrm{d}t $$

Integrating this is pretty simple,

$$ T(t) = 6.1867t + 0.807 \cos \Biggl (\dfrac{\pi}{12} t \Biggr ) \cdot \dfrac{12}{\pi} + C $$
I'm not sure where the $\ln$ came from, since the integral of $6.187$ and $\sin(\ldots)$ have nothing to do with logarithms.

Comment: The $\ln$ is just the constant of integration, processed a bit.  The whole term can be replaced by a new constant.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Still a very odd way to present it.